# while loop isn't updating the current savings variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I am working on a project, I am trying to complete a tutorial where you save monthly until you reach a certain amount for a down payment

These are inputs needed: annual salary(120,000), portion of salary to be saved(0.10), house cost(1,000,000)

```
annual_salary = float(input('Enter your annual salary: '))

portion_saved = float(input('Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal: '))

total_cost = float(input('Enter the cost of your dream home: '))
```

You have nothing saved up to begin with, months is used as a counter

```
current_savings = 0.0

months = 0

down_payment = 0.25*total_cost
```

Heres my while loop, I end up stopping the program myself and current_savings only updates once while months runs into the billions, why is this?

```
while current_savings < down_payment:
    current_savings = (current_savings*0.04)/12 + (annual_salary/12)*portion_saved
    months += 1
print('Number of months ', months)
```

current_savings*0.04 refers to a return on investment of 4% per annum, when I stop the program current_savings = 1003.3 which means its only calculated once.

Comment: `current_savings = (...)` must be `current_savings += (...)` because you want to _add_ the interest to the current savings, not _replace_ the current savings with the interest.

Answer (score 1):

I think that  the problem in the following line:

```
 current_savings = (current_savings*0.04)/12 + (annual_salary/12)*portion_saved
```

In Fact you need to increase the current_saving Like this:

```
current_savings += (current_savings*0.04)/12 + (annual_salary/12)*portion_saved
```

Because It's will be the same value in the loop 
So you need to increase it

Answer (score 0):

You update the savings to be just the interest gained, not what the savings *were* **plus** the interest.

I.e, the `current_savings` assignment should read:

```
current_savings = current_savings + (current_savings*0.04)/12 + (annual_salary/12)*portion_saved
```

Answer (score 0):

It's updating every time, but the math isn't right.  It's settling into an equilibrium:

`1000.0
1003.3333333333334
1003.3444444444444
1003.3444814814815
1003.3444816049383
1003.3444816053498
1003.3444816053511
1003.3444816053511
1003.3444816053511
1003.3444816053511
1003.3444816053511
1003.3444816053511
1003.3444816053511`

I think you need to add your current_savings back to itself so it increases:

`current_savings = current_savings + (current_savings*0.04)/12 + (annual_salary/12)*portion_saved`